# Remove array of arrays from array of arrays google sheets script/ javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a google script to grab multiple rows from multiple sheets put the columns in to and array of arrays and, grab existing and do the same, I then merge both arrays together and delete duplicates:

```
  var existingItems = getSKUdata()
  var newItems = getPurchasedata()
  var mergedData = existingData
  for (item of newItems) {
    mergedData.push(item)
  }
  const mergedCleaned = Array.from(new Set(mergedData.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse)
```

then remove any the arrays from 'existingItems' out of 'margedCleaned'.
so I can import the newly added items without having any duplicates.

Current arrays:

```
newItems = [
   ['AAA-AAA','AAAA', '01.00'],
   ['BBB-BBB','BBBB', '02.00'],
   ['CCC-CCC','CCCC', '03.00'],
   ['DDD-DDD','DDDD', '04.00']
];

existingItems = [
   ['AAA-AAA','AAAA', '01.00'],
   ['BBB-BBB','BBBB', '02.00'],
];
```

I want to 'newItems' to have all the 'existingItems' removed so I can write the new arrays/ rows to my google sheets document.

```
newItems= [
   ['CCC-CCC','CCCC', '03.00']
   ['DDD-DDD','DDDD', '04.00']
];
```

I have tried multiple different snippets from other questions but nothing seems to work it doesn't remove the arrays. Only can use core-javascript

Comment: I want to try remove the existing data from the array before pushing the data to help speed it up, or wouldn't it make much of a difference speed wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  using the joint array values as keys:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const newItems = [
    ['AAA-AAA', 'AAAA', '01.00'],
    ['BBB-BBB', 'BBBB', '02.00'],
    ['CCC-CCC', 'CCCC', '03.00'],
    ['DDD-DDD', 'DDDD', '04.00'],
  ],
  existingItems = [
    ['AAA-AAA', 'AAAA', '01.00'],
    ['BBB-BBB', 'BBBB', '02.00'],
  ],
  existingItemsSet = new Set(existingItems.map((row) => row.join('⚅'))),
  filteredNewItems = newItems.filter((row) =>
    !existingItemsSet.has(row.join('⚅'))
  );
console.log(filteredNewItems);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add after I've grabbed existing and new data I'm merging them and deleting duplicates so its just logging a blank array:
  var mergedData = existingItems
  for (item of newItem) {
    mergedData.push(item)
  }
  const mergedCleaned = Array.from(new Set(mergedData.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse)

Comment: @BlvckSZN So​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ?

Comment: When I run your script with it, it returns a blank array. when I remove the part where I remove duplicated items in the array it works fine

Comment: @BlvckSZN If you're still having trouble, ask a new question with sample data. Your latest modification to the question is unclear.